# C create and run windows service

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to create a service that will be run at system startup and start it immediately. Service is supposed to run my exe file.
GetLastError function return 1053 error code.

```
int main(void)
{
    SC_HANDLE SC_manager_handle;
    SC_HANDLE service_handle;
    LPCTSTR binary_path = "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\file.exe";
    LPCTSTR display_name = "ExampleService";
    LPCTSTR service_name = "EXAMPLE_SERVICE";

    SC_manager_handle = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

    puts("-----------------------");
    if(SC_manager_handle == NULL)
        puts("Open SM Manager: FAILED");
    else
        puts("SC Manager: SUCCESS");
    
    service_handle = CreateService(SC_manager_handle, service_name, display_name, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS ,SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, binary_path, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if(service_handle == NULL)
        puts("Create Service: FAILED");
    else
        puts("Service Create: SUCCESS");

    // running the exe file immediately
    if(!StartService(service_handle, 0, NULL))
        printf("Start Service: FAILED | ERROR: %d\n", GetLastError());
    else
        puts("Service Start: SUCCESS");

    CloseServiceHandle(SC_manager_handle);
    CloseServiceHandle(service_handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and in what question ?

Comment: `1053` is [ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-). You'll have to debug that in the actual service code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss some important requirements for a windows service.According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/services/using-services).

You need a service main function and a control handler function as you can't handle the "start" command if there's no control handler function registered.

So you can refer to the [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/services/svc-cpp) to know how to wrote a `ServiceMain` Function and install it.

If you want to open the service, according to [`Starting a Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/services/starting-a-service):

> To start a service, a service control program opens a handle to an
> installed database and then specifies the handle in a call to the
> StartService function. After starting the service, the program uses
> the members of the SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS structure returned by the
> QueryServiceStatusEx function to track the progress of the service.

I recommend you refer to the complete sample of using the service, which will greatly help you use the service.